# Minecraft wont maximize after entering and leaving full screen

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft won't maximize by the maximize square because I accidentally hit <kbd>F11</kbd> and went into full screen. I have tried to hit <kbd>F11</kbd> again but it wont work. I tried to quickly click on the maximize button, but it appears grey and wont even let me use it when I disable F11. My screen is either too big or too small. I dont know how to restart it.

Comment: Have you restarted Minecraft? That usually fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do not know much about this but what you could do is you could get your mouse and go to the sides. When an arrow appears (usually facing the top of your computer) click and drag it to what you would like the size to be. Or you could go into options and double click full screen.